# Why the compilation error for boolean and String

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have the below code

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i1=null;

    String s1=null;
    String s2=String.valueOf(i1);
    System.out.println(s1==null+" "+s2==null);//Compilation Error
    System.out.println(s1==null+" ");//No compilation Error
    System.out.println(s2==null+" ");//No compilation error
  }
}
```

Why there is compilation error if combine two Boolean with String

EDIT: The compilation Error is
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null

Comment: In future, if you're going to post code that doesn't compile and ask about the reason for the compilation error, please *include the error*.

Comment: Sorry , I have added the compilation error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of precedence. I can never remember all the precedence rules off the top of my head (and I don't try to) but I *suspect* the compiler is trying to interpret this as:

```
System.out.println((s1==(null+" "+s2))==null);
```

... and that doesn't make sense.

It's not clear what you're *expecting* any of those three lines to do, but you should use brackets to make your intentions clear to both the compiler and the reader. For example:

```
System.out.println((s1 == null) + " " + (s2==null));
System.out.println((s1 == null) + " ");
System.out.println((s2 == null) + " ");
```

Or you could make it clearer using local variables:

```
boolean s1IsNull = s1 == null;
boolena s2IsNull = s2 == null;

System.out.println(s1IsNull + " " + s2IsNull);
System.out.println(s1IsNull + " ");
System.out.println(s2IsNull + " ");
```

Comment: See http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php for a nice overview which operator is processed first.

Comment: @mszalbach: My normal rule of thumb is that if it's not obvious from the code, I should clarify it for other readers. I've very deliberately *not* learned all the rules.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However its only an addition why Java is behaving this way. And when someone reads this list he sees why its important to set "()" because there are a lot of priority rules.

Comment: @Jon Actually I was tiring to print both string are null or not in one line

Comment: @Krushna `((s1 == null) && (s2 ==null)) ? "Both are null" : "At least one is not null"`

Answer (score 2):

`+` gets processed before `==`.

This leads to `s1 == " " == null`